# Session Sharing and new Password

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have two applications in a workspace. 1st application: ID 42 and the 2nd application: ID 142

Now when I switch from one application to the other, I am always asked for the login data. This is annoying for the user.

Now in each of the application under Shared Components - Authentication Schemes - Session Sharing I set the Type to Custom and assigned a Cookie Name. I did this in both applications. Now the user can switch between the applications without entering the password again.

It should be noted that the app ID 42 has two entries: Application Express Authentication and Database - Current where I have enabled session sharing. App ID 142 has only Application Express Authentication.

Now, when a user logs in, he has to change his temporary password and now an error follows that only happens with the session sharing set. If it is not activated, the user can change his password, but must always log in again in every app.

The error message reads:The procedure named null could not be accessed. It may not be declared, or the user executing this request may not have execute permission for the procedure. Check the correct spelling of the procedure and make sure that the calling user has been granted the execute permission

What did I forget to set or does the new password not work with session sharing?